# strptime() causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c, date, time, strptime

I'm trying to parse a string into a `tm` struct using the `strptime()` function.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char raw_date1[100];
    char date1[100];
    struct tm *timedata1 = 0;

    printf("please provide the first date:");
    fgets(raw_date1, sizeof(raw_date1), stdin);

    strip_newline(date1, raw_date1, sizeof(raw_date1));

    char format1[50] = "%d-%m-%Y";

    strptime(date1, format1, timedata1);
```

On the last line, the program crashes with the message: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20)`.

Why?

Some extra info: According to the debugger, at the time of the crash, `date1` is `23/23/2323`, `format1` is `"%d-%m-%Y"` and `timedata1` is `NULL`.

Comment: try `struct tm timedata1;`.. `strptime(date1, format1, &timedata1);`

Comment: That did the trick. I don't understand why, though. To me, `timedata1` if declared as `struct tm *timedata;` is the same as `&timedata1` if `timedata1` is declared as `struct tm timedata;`.

Comment: The `strptime()` function wants to write in a `struct tm` that you are supposed to pass to it.  You passed a null pointer; it got upset.

Comment: `struct tm *timedata1 = 0;` defines a pointer, and you initialize it to 0 which is NULL.  Dereferencing a NULL pointer causes the exception.

Comment: Okay. How come the problem persists even if I don't initialise `timedata1` and only declare it? (See my question under Stephan Lechner's answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code:

```
struct tm *timedata1 = 0;
```

is the same as

```
struct tm *timedata1 = NULL;
```

Consequently, statement

```
strptime(date1, format1, timedata1);
```

is the same as

```
strptime(date1, format1, NULL);
```

i.e., in your code, you pass `NULL` as argument to `strptime`, which will dereference the pointer and yield undefined behaviour / bad access.

So you should write something like the following:

```
struct tm timedata1 = {0};
strptime(date1, format1, &timedata1);
```

Comment: So the fix is…?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: OP did not ask for the fix :-) ; no - I just had a look whether initialisation is required.

Comment: Got it, thanks. However, the same problem remains even if I write `struct tm *timedata1` (no `0`). I just wonder, why is that so? Because I thought that `type *var; var;` and `type var; &var;` were equivalent.

Comment: No, they are no equivalent. `type *var;` reserves memory for a pointer value, which remains uninitialised and "points to somewhere" (actually dereferencing it is undefined behaviour, probably bad access). `type var;`, in contrast, reserves memory for a value of type `type`, and `&var` gives then the address of this (valid) memory.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a null pointer to `strptime()` as a destination `tm` structure. This has undefined behavior.  You should instead pass a pointer to a `tm` structure defined as a local variable:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    char raw_date1[100];
    char date1[100];
    struct tm timedata1;

    printf("please provide the first date:");
    if (fgets(raw_date1, sizeof(raw_date1), stdin)) {
        strip_newline(date1, raw_date1, sizeof(raw_date1));

        char format1[50] = "%d-%m-%Y";

        strptime(date1, format1, &timedata1);

        ...
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that `strptime` is not a standard C function, although it is widely available as part of POSIX-1.2001.